# setting security rules in Cloud Firestore

Tags: android, database

The bottom line is that I am writing an application so that when you click on a button in an application, a person receives a promotional code from an array in the database and deletes this received line, but a problem has arisen, while simultaneously (or within 1-2 seconds) on different devices received one and also a value, since it simply does not have time to be removed from the base, so is it possible in the security rules to ask the users to access the database one by one or somehow solve this problem? Thank you in advance

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    Button mButtonGive;
    Button mButtonGiveIvi;
    TextView mTextPromo;
    TextView mTextPromoIvi;

    FirebaseFirestore mRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    DocumentReference mDelRef = mRef.collection("Promocode").document("Delivery");
    DocumentReference mIviRef = mRef.collection("Promocode").document("Ivi");


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mButtonGive = findViewById(R.id.mButtonGive);
        mButtonGiveIvi = findViewById(R.id.mButtonGiveIvi);
        mTextPromo = findViewById(R.id.mTextPromo);
        mTextPromoIvi = findViewById(R.id.mTextPromoIvi);

        mButtonGive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mDelRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                                assert document != null;
                                if (document.exists()) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
                                    List<String> promocodes;
                                    promocodes = (List<String>) document.get("Promocode");
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Promocodes: " + promocodes);
                                    if (promocodes.size() > 0) {
                                        mTextPromo.setText(promocodes.get(0));
                                        mDelRef.update("Promocode", FieldValue.arrayRemove(promocodes.get(0)));
                                    } else {
                                        mTextPromo.setText("Промокоды кончились");
                                        Log.d(TAG, "No Promo");
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
                                }

                            }
                            else {
                                Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
                            }
                    }

                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you posted no code or any snippet of your program:

I'm guessing you are sending a code to a user, and he has to introduce it in the app. Make another array where you keep track of sent codes that hasn't been used in the app yet: promotionalCodes[ ] and sentCodes[ ] for example. Once you want to send another code you should check if the code is in sentCodes[] and promotionalCodes[] so you don't send duplicates.

(It'd be easier if you attach some of the code or phrase your question better)

Comment: no, the essence is more than simple, the user opens the application, selects the application or site for which he needs a discount from the list, clicks on the "get" button, then he watches the commercial and after the video he has a promotional code which he can then use in this service

Comment: then make a double check: keep the code in the original list until its used and in another array as its has been sent to a user, but not used yet. So every time you send a new code you should check which ones you have already sent/used.

Comment: I understand what you want to say, you have to try, thanks

Comment: No, this method does not help, the problem is that it does not immediately delete or add values, and this delay is enough to get the same value on different devices